# Different verb foms in "not only … but also"

Tags: sentence-construction

As far as I know, words following both parts of this conjunction (not only and but also) should belong to the same parts of speech. For example, if a verb follows "not only" , then a verb should also follow "but also" .

> 1- The car not only ***is*** economical but also ***feels*** good to
>   drive.

After I have seen this sentence, I am wondering that do I have to use same verb form in both parts of this conjuction. For example: **If I use a verb in past simple form after "not only", does that mean do I have to use another verb in past simple after "but also"** ?

> 2- She not only ***sued*** him, but also ***wants*** money from him.
>
> 3- He not only ***has won*** the last Eisner, but he ***is also working*** for
>   another.

Are these examples grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the construction of the sentence.

For instance:

> 1. The car **is** not only economical but also good to drive.

In this version, no verb follows the *but*. This is possible because the verb *is* precedes *not only*. By parallel construction and elision, it applies to both parts of the sentence:

> 1. The car **is** not only economical but also <s>**is**</s> good to drive.

You don't need to provide the second instance of *is* since it's implicitly understood to be there.

However, if you don't actually want to imply ***is*** *good*, but actually want to say that it ***feels*** *good*, then you would still need to provide the second verb.

---

In your second sentence, there is no way of not providing a second verb because the following, although grammatical, would make no sense:

> ？ 2. She **sued** not only him but also <s>**sued**</s> his money.

---

So, if you move *not only* in front of the first verb, and the second verb you want to use is the *same* as the first verb, then you don't need to repeat it; otherwise, you do need a second verb.

Further note that you do not need *also*. It can be omitted in all of your sentences. The only part of the construction that's necessary is *not only . . . but*.

Comment: Thanks, ıs my third sentence okay?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden It's the same as the second sentence—in terms of the two verbs, it's also not one where I would omit the second one, simply because that would change the meaning of the sentence. (Although I might simplify it by removing some words—and making another slight edit: *He not only won the last Eisner, but is working toward another.*)